# pass data over the tree flutter

Tags: variables, dart, flutter

I search a simple solution to pass simple string variable over the tree widget, inherite function is to complicated to me.

to resume :

I tried to pass data to page 1 to body of page 2

---

```
 class page1 extends StatefulWidget 

 string textvariable

 onPressed: () {
  Navigator.push(
    context,
    new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new page2(
      textvariable: this,
    )),
  );
},
```

---

in my next page I have a StatelessWidget

```
 class page2 extends StatelessWidget {
 var textvariable;

page2({this.textvariable});
   @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("Localisation")),
    body: testwidget (textvariable),
  );
 }
}
```

---

I try to passe textvariable in the widget 3 who is a stateful

```
  class testwidget extends StatefulWidget
```

...

```
  new Text(
      "$textvariable",
      ),
```

Comment: Why are you passing `this` in your first snipped and not `textvariable`?

Comment: I don't know I tried some exemple I'm a little lost :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does BuildContext do in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49100196/what-does-buildcontext-do-in-flutter)

Comment: The answer here explain how you can pass data around routes

Comment: @RémiRousselet I also think that the OP should just overcome their fear, i.e. *"inherite function is to complicated to me"* and use an `InheritedWidget`.

Comment: There are a lot of way: See above: https://medium.com/flutter-community/simple-ways-to-pass-to-and-share-data-with-widgets-pages-f8988534bd5b