# flutter some cases using hyphen in buildContext space

Tags: flutter

BuildContext is show which widget in the tree
so each widget has that. and also i know why builder widget need in below example

```dart
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: new Container(),
      /// Builders let you pass context
      /// from your *current* build method
      /// Directly to children returned in this build method
      ///
      /// The 'builder' property accepts a callback
      /// which can be treated exactly as a 'build' method on any
      /// widget
      floatingActionButton: new Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return new FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () {
          Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
                new SnackBar(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                  content: new Text('SnackBar'),
                ),
              );
        });
      }),
    );
  }
```

Beacuse in floationactionbutton it has to know scaffold.
if i don't use builder that widget use context come from build function and that's not contain scaffold info
here is question
some cases i saw hyphen is used in context space

```
builder: (_) {}
```

like this

```dart
return Consumer<CounterProvider>
( builder: (_, counter, child) => Scaffold( appBar: AppBar( title: Text(widget.title), ),
```

or like this
how is it work? why context don't need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an underscore (not a hyphen) instead of specifying the parameter name if you don't use the value passed in to the parameter.

In your Consumer example, an underscore is used because `BuildContext` is not used in the builder function; you don't need it to instantiate `Scaffold`, `AppBar` and `Text`. On the other hand, you need one in order to call `Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar()`.

In the same manner, you can replace `counter` and `child` with `__` and `___` (double and triple underscores respectively) as they are not used as well. Note you cannot use a single underscore for each of them as it is already used in place of context.

---

**Example of usage of BuildContext in Consumer**

You can think that it works in the same way as in the `Builder` class.

```dart
Scaffold(
  body: ChangeNotifierProvider<Foo>(
    create: (context1) => Foo(),
    child: Consumer<Foo>(
      builder: (context2, foo, child) {
        return RaisedButton(
          child: Text(foo.message),
          onPressed: () {
            // You can get ScaffoldState using context2
            // which is impossible with context1
            Scaffold.of(context2).showSnackBar(...);
          },
        );
      },
    },
  ),
)
```

For more information, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49100439/12086560).

---

**What is builder?**

`builder` is an argument where you pass in a function, which is called when necessary with some values passed in for your convenience.

A lot of widgets have `builder`, but to take [Consumer](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/Consumer-class.html) as an example, it obtains some value given by `Provider()` somewhere up the tree, and then calls the builder function with values including the obtained one in order to build a widget tree using the widget returned from the function.

In your example, `Consumer` obtains the counter value from an ancestor and calls the `builder` function, passing in `BuildContext`, the counter value (obtained from an ancestor), and the child widget (which is `null` if you have omitted the `child` argument of `Consumer`).

Comment: and when buildcontext is it used in comsumer case? and what meaning in builder?