# AlertDialog Not Visible on Flutter Web App

Tags: flutter, dart

I am building a web app here. I am trying to show a dialog box to user who entered the wrong mail/password. Vs code indicates no error with the code but i cant see the alert box no matter what.
On Flutter Devtools i am just getting this message: DialogRoute

Howeve only the progress indicator is being shown but not the dialog.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class DesktopLoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const DesktopLoginPage({
    super.key,
    required this.emailController,
    required this.passwordController,
  });

  final TextEditingController emailController;
  final TextEditingController passwordController;

  @override
  State<DesktopLoginPage> createState() => _DesktopLoginPageState();
}

class _DesktopLoginPageState extends State<DesktopLoginPage> {
  void signUserIn() async {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return const Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      },
    );

    try {
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: widget.emailController.text,
          password: widget.passwordController.text);

      Navigator.pop(context);
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      Navigator.pop(context);

      if (e.code == "user-not-found") {
        wrongEmailMessage();
      } else if (e.code == "wrong-password") {
        wrongPasswordMessage();
      }
    }
  }

  void wrongEmailMessage() {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return const AlertDialog(
          title: Text("Hatalı mail adresi girdiniz"),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  void wrongPasswordMessage() {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return const AlertDialog(
          title: Text("Hatalı parola girdiniz"),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.blue.shade100,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 300.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            const Text("Giriş Yapın"),
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
            TextField(
              controller: widget.emailController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                fillColor: Colors.white,
                filled: true,
                hintText: "E-posta Adresiniz",
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
            TextField(
              obscureText: true,
              controller: widget.passwordController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                fillColor: Colors.white,
                filled: true,
                hintText: "Parolanız",
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
            TextButton(
              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                backgroundColor: Colors.pink.shade100,
                shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                    Radius.circular(5),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              onPressed: signUserIn,
              child: const Text("Giriş Yap"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

##### The problem

In your function, you are calling the `showDialog`:

```dart
 void signUserIn() async {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return const Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      },
    );
```

as you can see, it expects a `context` parameter, this parameter expects a [`BuildContext`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BuildContext-class.html) so that it should know where to show the dialog.

so what you want is to pass a BuildContext to the `singUserIn` function which would then be used in the dialog.

##### Solution

First accept the `BuildContext` in your function:

```dart
void signUserIn(BuildContext context) async {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return const Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      },
    );
```

and then call it with:

```dart
 onPressed: () => signUserIn(context),
              child: const Text("Giriş Yap"),
```

*Do the same for the other methods.*

###### See also

- [What does BuildContext do in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49100196/12349734)

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot for the help. I did as you told but still the same. I tried adding "context" inside wrongEmailMessage() and wrongPasswordMessage() as well but result is the same. I dont get the issue.